# Push back Data into Matrix and show that matrix using imshow

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I'm new to opencv and its developing. I want to push back unsigned data two two Dimensional  matrix into Mat type object. and show that Mat using imshow (opencv function) Please find the below code snippit which i tried. but i'm getting errors. any help is appriated.

```
Mat finaldata(20, 10000, CV_8UC1);
unsigned char test[20][10000]={"0"};// test having values i checked it.

    for (int coloumns=0 ;coloumns <20;coloumns++)
        {
            for (int row=0 ;row <10000;row++)
            {
                finaldata.push_back(test[coloumns][row]);
            }

        }

        imshow("window ", finaldata);
        waitKey(0);
```

Error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (DataType<_Tp>::type == type() && cols == 1) in push_back, file /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp, line 690
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:690: error: (-215) DataType<_Tp>::type == type() && cols == 1 in function push_back

Program ended with exit code: 9
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: probably not the problem but Mat finaldata(20, 10000, CV_8UC1) means 20 ROWS and 10000 columns

Comment: @Micka i changed it but still i'm getting the same error. any idea ?

Comment: I never used the mat.push_back myself yet, but I'll have a look

Comment: as far as I see, `mat.push_back will add another ROW to your matrix. So you create a 20x10000 matrix and you try to add another single element as a new row. That doesn't work because your rows have 10000 columns and not just 1 column.

Comment: @Micka could you please post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I see, `mat.push_back will add another ROW to your matrix. So you create a 10000x20 matrix and you try to add another single element as a new row. That doesn't work because your rows have 20 columns and not just 1 column.

So this would work:

```
cv::Mat finaldata(0, 0, CV_8UC1);
unsigned char test[20][10000]={"0"};// test having values i checked it.
for (int coloumns=0 ;coloumns <20;coloumns++)
    {
        for (int row=0 ;row <10000;row++)
        {
           finaldata.push_back(test[coloumns][row]);
        }

    }
```

but here you'll end up with a 200000x1 matrix. You could use `cv::reshape` or similar like:

```
finaldata = finaldata.reshape(1,10000); // if 10000 should be the number of rows.
```

You could however instead use your data directly without any copying (a pointer to the data is used):

```
unsigned char test[20][10000]={"0"};// test having values i checked it.
cv::Mat finaldata(10000, 20, CV_8UC1, &test);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you can add simple arrays using push_back function. I would prefer using the following way:

```
cv::Mat finaldata(20, 10000, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat zero = cv::Mat::zeros(1, 10000, CV_8UC1);

for (int coloumns = 0; coloumns <20; coloumns++)
{
    finaldata.push_back(zero);
}

cv::imshow("window ", finaldata);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

Comment: this will end in a 40x10000 matrix